# Maven Deploy/Install Not Resolved

Tags: java, maven

I'm having trouble getting Maven to load some of my plug-ins. I either get an error saying these plug-ins weren't found or weren't resolved. I'm not sure why it can find some but not others.

Error:

> Plugin 'maven-install-plugin:' not found

[image: Found clean and site, but not deploy and install?]

I have tried changing the Maven home path, unchecking work offline, use the plugin registries, updating the snapshots, automatically download sources/documentations/annotations.

I have also invalidated cache, and reloaded all Maven projects, and deleted the plugins from the `.m2` folder.

Am I missing something simple here? I am a Maven noob.

Thanks,

A

Comment: Please run on plain command line and show the log output...

Comment: Plus it is much better to add the pom.xml, the project structure, and any other related information as text, not as images.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1744774)

Comment: Good starting point for Maven noobs: https://maven.apache.org/